# Default value for the same field, different depending on content type

Tags: entities, nodes

I am building a website and have 3 content-types.

```
Type A
Type B
Type C
```

I built these content types one after another, and `used existing field` when creating the content-type field `Field`.

My question is, how do I set a default value for `Field` for each of my content-types ?
Right now when I set a default it is default for all my content-types.

I want to have

```
Type A -> Field = value 1
Type B -> Field = value 2
Type C -> Field = value 3
```

Comment: i think you should use distinct fields for that if you do not want to set a default value programmaticly

Comment: so, this cannot be done unless i do some custom code, right ?
I'm asking because this is the situation right now, on a project that I'm continuing, I did not develop it from scratch, I just have to improve it and add some custom functionalities.

Comment: If you mean there is already custom code doing it, that is a perfectly acceptable solution. It would only require a very small amount of custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve you goal with the rules module, as @pico34 wrote in his answer, but use the trigger `Before saving content` instead of `After saving new content`.

Alternativey, if you need to do that programmatically, you can define your default values in just a few lines of code using [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

**Example**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_node_presave($node) {
  // set the value of field "field_somefield" in case of node type: a, b or c.
  if (in_array($node->type, array('a', 'b', 'c')) && empty($node->field_somefield[$node->language][0]['value'])) {
    switch ($node->type) {
      case 'a' :
        $node->field_somefield[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Default value for A';
        break;
      case 'b' :
        $node->field_somefield[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Default value for B';
        break;
      case 'c' :
        $node->field_somefield[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Default value for C';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules)

For each content type, add a rule :

- The event trigger is : after saving new content
- Add a distinct condition on each: content is type 'foo'
- Add another condition : 'data value is empty' on your field
- Add an action : "Set a data value" and select your field and add your default value

OR pre-populate the field in the form

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    switch ($form_id) {

      case 'typea_node_form':
        if (!$form['nid']['#value']) {// = add only
          $form['field_custom']['und'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = 'default_a';
        }          
        break;

      case 'typeb_node_form':
      // the same...
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that overwrite any value the user enters? Don't you need a condition to say "if the field is empty"? However then in that case the user could never make the field empty like they can by removing the default value normally, which may or may not be an issue depending on whether the field is required or not.